# Issue with Java Server class and socket connections

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

I am trying to set up a server class, and i'm running into a issue in which no error is being thrown.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Server extends JFrame implements Runnable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JTextField userText;
private JTextArea chatWindow;
private ObjectOutputStream output;
private ObjectInputStream input;
private ServerSocket server;
private Socket connection;

//constructor
public Server(){
    super("Server");
    userText = new JTextField();
    userText.setEditable(false);
    userText.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                sendMessage(event.getActionCommand());
                userText.setText("");
            }
        }
    );
    add(userText, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    chatWindow = new JTextArea();
    add(new JScrollPane(chatWindow));
    setSize(300, 150); //Sets the window size
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);   
}

public void run(){
    try{
        server = new ServerSocket(6789, 100); //6789 is a dummy port for testing, this can be changed. The 100 is the maximum people waiting to connect.
        while(true){
            try{
                //Trying to connect and have conversation
                waitForConnection();
                setupStreams();
                whileChatting();
            }catch(EOFException eofException){
                showMessage("\n Server ended the connection! ");
            } finally{
                closeConnection(); //Changed the name to something more appropriate
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}
//wait for connection, then display connection information
private void waitForConnection() throws IOException{
    showMessage(" Waiting for someone to connect... \n");
    connection = server.accept();
    showMessage(" Now connected to " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
}

//get stream to send and receive data
private void setupStreams() throws IOException{
    output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    output.flush();

    input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

    showMessage("\n Streams are now setup \n");
}

//during the chat conversation
private void whileChatting() throws IOException{
    String message = " You are now connected! ";
    sendMessage(message);
    ableToType(true);
    do{
        try{
            message = (String) input.readObject();
            showMessage("\n" + message);
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException){
            showMessage("The user has sent an unknown object!");
        }
    }while(!message.equals("CLIENT - END"));
}

public void closeConnection(){
    showMessage("\n Closing Connections... \n");
    ableToType(false);
    try{
        output.close(); //Closes the output path to the client
        input.close(); //Closes the input path to the server, from the client.
        connection.close(); //Closes the connection between you can the client
    }catch(IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//Send a mesage to the client
private void sendMessage(String message){
    try{
        output.writeObject("SERVER - " + message);
        output.flush();
        showMessage("\nSERVER -" + message);
    }catch(IOException ioException){
        chatWindow.append("\n ERROR: CANNOT SEND MESSAGE, PLEASE RETRY");
    }
}

//update chatWindow
private void showMessage(final String text){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
        new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                chatWindow.append(text);
            }
        }
    );
}

private void ableToType(final boolean tof){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
        new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                userText.setEditable(tof);
            }
        }
    );
 }
 }



import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Menu extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JButton server;
private JButton client;
private static String Host;

public Menu(){

    this.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));

    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLayout(null);
    this.pack();

    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    server = new JButton();
    server.setText("server");
    server.setBounds(0, 0, 300, 150);
    server.addActionListener(this);
    client = new JButton();
    client.setText("client");
    client.setBounds(0, 150, 300, 150);
    client.addActionListener(this);

    this.add(server);
    this.add(client);

    this.setVisible(true);
}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == server){
        Server s = new Server();
        s.run();
    }
    if(e.getSource() == client){
        Host = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Server I.P.");
        Client c = new Client(Host);
        c.run();
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args){
    new Menu();
}

}
```

The JFrame is created, but can only be exited by the termination button in eclipse, not the default_exit_on_close operation, and is see through (not opaque as it should be). The client class acts the same way, leading me to believe that the issue is the:

```
 Server s = new Server();
        s.run();
```

since if i have the main method call that, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor can never exit.

This `waitForConnection()/setUpStreams()` logic is not appropriate. You need an accept *loop* that just accepts sockets, constructs a `Runnable` to handle the connection, and starts a thread. That loop should be in a separate `run()` method and be executed in a separate thread. Not in a constructor.

NB The `Socket` that is returned by `accept()` must be a local variable in that loop, otherwise you are liable to run into concurrency problems.

Comment: when i copied the exact code from the tutorial (I made it so it was a Runnable) it worked fine. He had the main method create and only create the server. but if i create a menu class, and have a jbutton construct the server, i get the same issue, leading me to believe there is some issue in how the server is constructed. i also added the tutorial code as well as my menu class

Comment: I am unable to understand from all that whether you have now solved your original problem. You must execute both your Server and your client in new separate threads, not in the AWT event thread. If this code is from a tutorial you should find a better one. It is not how servers are written in Java.

Comment: executing the server in the AWT event thread (JButtons) has been the problem since the very begging, I was unaware of that being a thing and assumed it was somewhere else initially. I am making a game that hopefully can be used as a server or client, which is what i was hoping to accomplish in my menu class

Comment: I've looked online and found that i need to use multi threading in some way, with many people from stack saying to use invokeLater. I couldn't really find where to put it though. would you by any chance be either show me in my code where to put that, or point me towards a place that could fully explain it? I'm having a huge amount of trouble finding full detailed explanations or examples.